# How to generate a PDF file by Code?

Tags: r, pdf, latex, knitr, sweave

I'm absolutely new to R, RStudio, LaTeX, knitr and even stackoverflow. I want to generate a pdf file in RStudio via LaTeX.

I've written the following script, which is working totally fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<setup, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE>>=
library("xtable")
source("D:\\Programming\\Testing\\2017-03-13\\UniDF.R")
@

<<xtable, results = "asis", echo=FALSE>>=
print(xtable(uni_kassel), type = "latex")
@

<<barplot, echo=FALSE, results='hide'>>=
#Loop through rows in df
for (i in seq(from = 1, to = nrow(uni_kassel), by = 1))
{
  #Create subset from df
  data <- matrix(c(subset(uni_kassel$Studenten, 
                          fb == uni_kassel$Fachbereich[i]), 
                   subset(uni_kassel$Absolventen, 
                          fb == uni_kassel$Fachbereich[i])))

  #Create first barplot
  print(source("D:\\Programming\\Testing\\2017-03-08\\SimpleBarChart.R"))
}
@

\end{document}
```

I would be really grateful for some help.

Comment: Have you tried `library(knitr)` `knit2pdf("path_to_your_Rnw_file")`?

Comment: I just did now and it works. Seems like I am unable to google correctly. Thank you for your fast answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [J_F](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6045390/j-f) I was able to solve my problem.

The solution was pretty simple:

```
library(knitr)
knit2pdf("path_to_your_Rnw_file")
```